# Blank "Location" header but redirect happens in IE

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

I am trying to access a URL with HttpURLCONNECTION object, but the redirect just does not seem to be identified because the Location header is blank. Is there any other way I can follow the redirects. setFollowRedirects also is not helping.

```
private static boolean isLive(String link) {
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
try {
  URL url = new URL(link);
  System.out.println(url);
  urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
  urlConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
  urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
 // urlConnection.connect();

  //urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(5000); /* timeout after 5s if can't connect */
  //urlConnection.setReadTimeout(5000); /* timeout after 5s if the page is too slow */
  urlConnection.connect();
  int resp = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
  System.out.println(resp);
  String redirectLink = urlConnection.getHeaderField("Location");
  System.out.println(redirectLink);
  if (redirectLink != null && !link.equals(redirectLink)) {
    return isLive(redirectLink);
  } else {
    return urlConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK;
  }
} catch (Exception e) {
  return false;
} finally {
  if (urlConnection != null) {
    urlConnection.disconnect();
  }
}
```

Comment: what's the Response you get from the HTTP Server? Is it a public server? Can you post the URL or can you post the Response (Status, Headers,...) ?

Comment: it is an internal application.. but I found something that works similarly https://www0.bankofamerica.com/home-loans/mortgage-purchase.go

Comment: Using your example URL I get a `HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently` with
`Location: https://www9.bankofamerica.com/home-loans/mortgage-purchase.go`. Are you sure that the Location Header is blank? Or is there something like redirect via JavaScript or Refresh Meta Tag in your page?

Comment: wow.. thats something quite unlike what I am getting here. can you please let me know how you got the redirect information. For your reference here is the code I am using. Somehow I don't think that this code is not able to establish the connection.

Comment: I'm using curl `curl --verbose --insecure  https://www0.bankofamerica.com/home-loans/mortgage-purchase.go` and get the response `< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Date: Sun, 15 Apr 2012 09:00:59 GMT
< Server: IBM_HTTP_Server
< Location: https://www9.bankofamerica.com/home-loans/mortgage-purchase.go`

Comment: I have edited my question and posted the code. Somehow I am not able to get this to work for the example URL. Could you please help.The status is always returned as false

Comment: I've used a slightly modified version with improved output and it gives: "link: https://www0.bankofamerica.com/home-loans/mortgage-purchase.go
301
Location : https://www7.bankofamerica.com/home-loans/mortgage-purchase.go
link: https://www7.bankofamerica.com/home-loans/mortgage-purchase.go
200
Location : null
isLive https://www7.bankofamerica.com/home-loans/mortgage-purchase.go =  true"

Comment: would you be able to help me with what I need to edit in my code. Any help would be of great use for me

Comment: I'm trying to help you. Something like the curl output would be helpful.

Comment: yeah.. That would be really great.. Did you have any luck running my code? I think the problem is with the URL throwing an exception.This is what I got javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Comment: The SSLHandshakeException is not really a Problem. I've posted my slightly modified code below. With this code I recieved a HTTP StatusCode 301 with Location Header. See comment #7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slightly modified code which ignores SSL Certificate Errors

```
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;




public class RedirectTest {


    private static boolean isLive(String link) {
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try {
          URL url = new URL(link);
          System.out.println("link: " + url);
          urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();          
          urlConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
          urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
         // urlConnection.connect();

          //urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(5000); /* timeout after 5s if can't connect */
          //urlConnection.setReadTimeout(5000); /* timeout after 5s if the page is too slow */
          urlConnection.connect();
          int resp = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
          System.out.println(resp);
          String redirectLink = urlConnection.getHeaderField("Location");
          System.out.println("Location : " + redirectLink);
          if (redirectLink != null && !link.equals(redirectLink)) {
            boolean b = isLive(redirectLink);   
            System.out.println("isLive " + redirectLink + " =  " + b);
            return b;
          } else {
            return urlConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK;
          }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LoggerFactory.getLogger(RedirectTest.class).debug("Exception", e);
          return false;
        } finally {
          if (urlConnection != null) {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
          }
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

     // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{
            new X509TrustManager() {
                public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    return null;
                }
                public void checkClientTrusted(
                    java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                }
                public void checkServerTrusted(
                    java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                }
            }
        };

        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());


        isLive("https://www0.bankofamerica.com/home-loans/mortgage-purchase.go");
    }
}
```